# el botón de borrar no funciona correctamente en todo-list con javaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estoy desarrollando este todo-list con html, css y js
Cada item de la lista tiene un checkbox para marcarlo cuando la tarea ha sido realizada, y un botón para eliminarla. 
Al presionar el boton borrar recibo el siguiente error:

> *app.js:30 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on
>   'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
>       at trashItem (app.js:30)
>       at app.js:45 trashItem @ app.js:30 (anonymous) @ app.js:45*

Éste es el código javaScript que estoy aplicando:

```js
const deleted= document.getElementsByClassName("delete");
const list= document.getElementById("list");
const input= document.getElementById("input");
const item= document.getElementById("item");
const checked= document.getElementsByClassName("check");

function trashItem(){
    list.removeChild(item);
}

function addToDo(itemValue){

    itemValue= input.value;
    const text= `
                <li id="item">
                    <p class="text">${itemValue}</p>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="check" >
                    <input type="button" class="delete">
                </li> `;
    list.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",text);
    console.log(list)
}
deleted.addEventListener("click",trashItem());
document.addEventListener("keyup",(event)=>{ if(event.keyCode===13){addToDo()}});
```

Y a continuación adjunto el html de la tarea:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

    <title>To Do List</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="clear">
                <i class="refresh" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
            <div id="date"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="add-item">
            <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Add Something to Do">
            <button type="submit" id="button" onclick="addToDo()">Click Me</button>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <ul id="list">
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
    <script src="app.js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas asignando mal el evento

```
const deleted = document.getElementsByClassName("delete");
```

esto no selecciona nada porque al iniciar la aplicación no hay elementos al cual asignarle la funcion **trashItem** de modo que deberas asignarle los eventos a cada item que agregas

```js
const deleted = document.getElementsByClassName("delete");
const list= document.getElementById("list");
const input= document.getElementById("input");
const item= document.getElementById("item");
const checked= document.getElementsByClassName("check");

let toDo = []

function trashItem(){
    list.removeChild(this);
}

function addToDo(itemValue){

    itemValue= input.value;
    toDo.push(itemValue)
    
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    const text= `<p class="text">${itemValue}</p>
                <input type="checkbox" class="check" >
                <input type="button" class="delete" value="Borrar"> `;
    li.innerHTML = text;
    li.classList.add('item')
    
    list.appendChild(li);
    addEvents(li)
}

function addEvents(item){
  item.addEventListener("click", trashItem);
}

document.addEventListener("keyup",(event)=>{ if(event.keyCode===13){addToDo()}});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

    <title>To Do List</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="clear">
                <i class="refresh" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
            <div id="date"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="add-item">
            <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Add Something to Do">
            <button type="submit" id="button" onclick="addToDo()">Click Me</button>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <ul id="list">
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
    <script src="app.js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```